# Pontryagin charge of $SO(3)$ connection on a bundle over a $4$-manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes

On page 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.5365.pdf, the authors write:

Given any $SO(3)$ connection $A$ on a bundle $E$ over a (not necessarily compact) $4$-manifold, $Z$, let $F(A)$ denote its curvature $2$-form. Define the Pontryagin charge of $A$ to be the real number
$$p_1(A)=-\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_Z\text{Tr}(F(A)\wedge F(A)),$$
provided this integral converges. When $Z$ is closed, $p_1(A)=\langle p_1(E),[Z]\rangle\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Can you give a few examples of how to compute the Pontryagin charge?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $E$ is the direct sum of an $SO(2) = U(1)$ bundle $L$ and a trivial line bundle $\varepsilon^1$, then

$$p_1(E) = p_1(L\oplus\varepsilon^1) = p_1(L) = -c_2(L\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}) = -c_2(L\oplus\overline{L}) = -c_1(L)c_1(\overline{L}) = c_1(L)^2.$$

If you know enough about $L$ and $Z$, then this allows you to compute the Pontryagin charge.

**Example:** On $\mathbb{CP}^2$, if $E = \mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\varepsilon^1$, then

$$p_1(A) = \langle p_1(E), [\mathbb{CP}^2]\rangle = \langle c_1(\mathcal{O}(k))^2, [\mathbb{CP}^2]\rangle = \langle(k\alpha)^2, [\mathbb{CP}^2]\rangle =  \langle k^2\alpha^2, [\mathbb{CP}^2]\rangle = k^2$$

where $\alpha = c_1(\mathcal{O}(1))$ is a generator for $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^2; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{O}(k)$? Why is $E$ a direct sum? Thank you!

Comment: I said *if* $E = \mathcal{O}(k)\oplus\varepsilon^1$ (it isn't necessarily of that form). Here $\mathcal{O}(k)$ denotes the line bundle with Chern class $k\alpha$, it isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(1)^{\otimes k}$. These bundles arise naturally in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Is this $E$ the associated vector bundle of a principal $SO(3)$ bundle? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: The principal $SO(2)$ bundle $P_{SO(2)}$ associated to $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is $S^5\to\mathbb{CP}^2$, what is the principal $SO(3)$ bundle associated to $\mathcal{O}(1)\oplus\varepsilon^1$? Is it $P_{SO(2)}\times_{SO(2)}SO(3)$? Thank you very much!

Comment: @ZheyanWan: Yes, that's right.